# Prevent access by views

Tags: jquery, html

I have a website that loads using jquery a series of views that are in a "view" folder.
How I can prevent people from accessing that folder or any of its contents by directly opening their URL in the browser?
I want them to be only accessible via jQuery from index.html.

Comment: Could you explain your question better?

Comment: You can restrict folder by it's permission

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi But then jQuery couldn't load it either.

Comment: @Siguza i mean that he can restirct folder access that external user can't access that folder like entering www.example.com/foldername but that not means that he can't load jquery from that folder

Comment: prevent unwanted access to .html files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. Not bulletproof anyway.

Long answer:

When jQuery loads something, that loading process is executed by the browser.  Therefore, anything that jQuery can load, the browser can load.

However, you can make it **very troublesome** for people.
You could, for example, use a server-side script (like PHP) to check if the following header is set and deny the page otherwise:

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

That is **usually** only the case when the request has been made via AJAX, but there is **no guarantee**.